# how to make href links fire C# methods when clicked

Tags: c#, methods, href

What I basically want to do is when I click on an href link in html it should fire a C# method attached to that link. What are my options on doing this? the html onclick only looks for javascript functions. also note I am not linking to another page, I just want to use it to add arguments to the URL and then run C# and use those arguments in a method.

Comment: How are you "hosting" this html page?

Comment: You can use a `LinkButton` if you are writing an ASP .NET WebForms application.

Comment: is it possible to make a LinkButton create another LinkButton When clicking on the first LinkButton?

Comment: @5tar-Kaster - Like LinkButton Inception? Depends what you mean a `LinkButton` usually calls server side code, so you could then create another `LinkButton` on the server? What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @Belogix I want to basically dynamicaly create a bunch of LinkButtons based on an unknown number of entries in a database, thats my end goal of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to create a C# webmethod or WebAPI which you would use ajax to call.  You can not access a C# method directly from html or javascript unless you are using something like a server side control (LinkButton) which you could then add a C# handler for the click of that button.

So client side your 'onClick' would execute a javascript function.  The Javascript function would call the C# webmethod, passing in the parameters, then onSuccess you would have the results and do with them as you please.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your values in hidden field with form ,

```
<form name="FUN" method="post" action="FUN.aspx" onsubmit='return funCheckProgramName()' >
        <input name="userAction" type="hidden" value="submitName">

    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
function funSearchProgram()
{
    document.FUN.userAction.value="submitName";
}
    -----------------------------
```

Here you can have a single value which you want to post or you can use javascript to assign value to your hidden field .

=============================================================================

```
 **string str = Request.Form["userAction"].ToString();**

          =====================================
```

Now you have your value you can add handler

```
if (userAction.Trim ().Equals ("submitName")) 
        submitNameHandler();

    private void submitNameHandler()
    {
               //Your Code goes here .
            }
```